# Number of constant-sum combinations

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Suppose you are given `n` lists of integers `L1,L2,...,Ln` and an integer `S`.

I am looking for a way to efficiently count the combinations of indexes `j1,j2,...,jn` such that `L1[j1]+L2[j2]+...+Ln[jn] = S`.

As an example, take `L1=[0,1,1,2], L2=[0,1], L3=[0,1,2,3,3]` and `S=4`.
Then the possible combinations are

```
0+1+3
0+1+3
1+0+3
1+0+3
1+1+2
1+0+3
1+0+3
1+1+2
2+0+2
2+1+1
```

i.e. the answer I am looking for is `10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it with DP. Complexity: O(nS).

```
Count(i,s) = \sum_j=0..s Count(i-1,j) * Number of elements in list i with value (s-j)
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem is NP complete. You can

1) Brute force it

or, if you have some extra properties (the total sums involved are small, for example) you can also consider

2) Use dynamic programming to get a pseudopolinomial algorithm.